# Echolink for Android not showing repeater node

Tags: echolink

Planning to travel out of state, I decided to try using echolink to connect with my local repeater. I validated my callsign and successfully connected to the test server. I decided to try connecting to KE6TZG by searching for the callsign in the app, but I couldn't find it. There were no stations in search results for KE6TZG but when I searched for KE6 I got a list of some local stations.

According to kpra.net the node is "idle" which I assume means it is empty and available. I would be connecting though 3g/4g or WiFi, though I would not have router setting access so I would need to go through a relay server, would that cause the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node is reported as currently offline.
https://www.repeaterbook.com/repeaters/echolink/node_status.php?node=KE6TZG-R&type=search

The notes on the repeater at RepeaterBook do say that incoming connections are restricted.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much! I wonder why the graphic on the site was incorrect. Hmm...

Comment: Good question.  I wondered if they had an Internet problem, where their web site (maybe hosted at the same site as the echolink node) could reach it but nobody else on the outside could.  The little widget does say (when not saying "monitor timed out") that the last "out" (outgoing connection?) was 7/19, and shows nothing for "in", all of which is suspicious.